# Why is jshint exported directive not working?

Tags: javascript, jshint

In my file `matte_design.js`:

```
/*exported matte_design_change */
/*exported matte_design_populate_types */

...


function matte_design_change(cid, selected_type, x, y, opening_width, opening_height)
{
  ...
}

...

function matte_design_populate_types()
{
  ...
}
```

These functions are used in other files. Even with the `exported` directive I am still getting the error: `'matte_design_change' is defined but never used` and `'matte_design_populate_types' is defined but never used`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem when I copy that code to jshint.

Comment: I'm not getting anything either

Comment: Did you try to produce it will the function calls from another file?